# Laravel 5.2 with Angularjs route

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, url, routes

I followed this tuturioal (http://learninglaravel.net/laravel-52-and-angularjs-crud-with-search-and-pagination-example/link) and it works only using:

`php artisan serve`

When I try to access by "localhost/myapp/public" I have a problem with

> " page not found ".

How should I write the routes to work with `artisan serve` and my apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to follow  "localhost/myapp/public" 
just open your CMD inside your project root
then run :`php artisan serve`
it will run your app with loacalhost:8000
follow it and there we go :)

Comment: I know how to use `artisan serve` , but I dont want to. If you know how to fix the routes... I appreciate any help. :-)

Comment: ok if you don't need to user [serve] command , just run it from your local server like WAMP , that worked for me :)

Comment: could you put your routes file here please ?

Comment: It's in the link... too long to put here.